# Trying to JSON.parse serialized data from Django

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, django

I want to do some stuff on the client using Javascript. I serialize a Queryset from my models in JSON in my view and send it to the template.

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", Profile.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user))
```

I end up with this:

```
var data = '[
                {
                    "model": "accounts.profile", 
                    "pk": 14, 
                    "fields": {
                        "user": 14, 
                        "email_confirmed": true, 
                        "encrypted_private_key": "Z0FBQUFBQmJLQT09", 
                        "public_key": "LS0tLSS0tLQo=", 
                        "salt": "I8rzovcWsKm4G5Pj3E4DMw=="
                              }
                }
            ]';
```

When I try to do:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{{ data|safe }}');
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: May be that mean that JSON can't start with `[`? May be you need change like this: `Profile.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user)[0]`?

Comment: try using the `{{ data|safe }}` with a variable before `JSON.parse(variable_name)`,

Comment: Unfortunately none of your suggestions worked. I'm tried creating a global variable in my HTML file like `var data = {{ data|safe }};` and the access it from my javascript file but it gives the same error. I tried setting the variable with and without quotes and also with backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains newlines, so

```
var data = JSON.parse('{{ data|safe }}');
```

is not going to work. Try using back-ticks (not sure how to enter them here) rather than `'`.

However, if you've already dumped the data to json, you don't need to parse it on the JS side, simply do

```
var data = {{ data|safe }};
```

**update:** note, there are no quotes around the template variable above, and the above will turn into (check it in view-source):

```
var data = [
            {
                "model": "accounts.profile", 
                "pk": 14, 
                "fields": {
                    "user": 14, 
                    "email_confirmed": true, 
                    "encrypted_private_key": "Z0FBQUFBQmJLQT09", 
                    "public_key": "LS0tLSS0tLQo=", 
                    "salt": "I8rzovcWsKm4G5Pj3E4DMw=="
                          }
            }
        ];
```

note, still no quotes around it.  This is valid Javascript, no further action (ie. parsing) needed.

**update2:** to use this data in a .js file, you'll need to change your .js file like this:

```
var some_unique_name = function (data) {
    ... original code goes here ...
};
```

and in your html:

```
<script src="...your script"></script>
<script>
    some_unique_name({{ data|safe }});
</script>
```

**update3:** the above will expand to (check this using your browser's view-source function):

```
<script src="...your script"></script>
<script>
    some_unique_name([
            {
                "model": "accounts.profile", 
                "pk": 14, 
                "fields": {
                    "user": 14, 
                    "email_confirmed": true, 
                    "encrypted_private_key": "Z0FBQUFBQmJLQT09", 
                    "public_key": "LS0tLSS0tLQo=", 
                    "salt": "I8rzovcWsKm4G5Pj3E4DMw=="
                          }
            }
        ]);
</script>
```

which is valid javascript.  You cannot blindly do the same in a html event handler though, since

```
<button type="button" onclick="some_unique_name({{ data|safe }})" ...>
```

will expand to

```
    <button type="button" onclick="some_unique_name([
            {
                "model": "accounts.profile",    // syntax error here..
                "pk": 14, 
                "fields": {
                    "user": 14, 
                    "email_confirmed": true, 
                    "encrypted_private_key": "Z0FBQUFBQmJLQT09", 
                    "public_key": "LS0tLSS0tLQo=", 
                    "salt": "I8rzovcWsKm4G5Pj3E4DMw=="
                          }
            }
        ])" ...>
```

which the browser will see as

```
<button type="button" onclick="some_unique_name([{"
```

which it doesn't understand.

If we disregard Django for a second, there are two obvious fixes to this problem:

(1) put the parameter to the function in a variable:

```
<script>
    var my_variable = [
            {
                "model": "accounts.profile",    // syntax error here..
                "pk": 14, 
                "fields": {
                    "user": 14, 
                    "email_confirmed": true, 
                    "encrypted_private_key": "Z0FBQUFBQmJLQT09", 
                    "public_key": "LS0tLSS0tLQo=", 
                    "salt": "I8rzovcWsKm4G5Pj3E4DMw=="
                          }
            }
        ];
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="some_unique_name(my_variable);">..</button>
```

(2) or wrap the call in a function:

```
<script>
    var foo = function () {
        some_unique_name([
            {
                "model": "accounts.profile",    // syntax error here..
                "pk": 14, 
                "fields": {
                    "user": 14, 
                    "email_confirmed": true, 
                    "encrypted_private_key": "Z0FBQUFBQmJLQT09", 
                    "public_key": "LS0tLSS0tLQo=", 
                    "salt": "I8rzovcWsKm4G5Pj3E4DMw=="
                          }
            }
        ]);
    };
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="foo();">..</button>
```

Getting back to Django this becomes

(1)

```
<script>
    var my_variable = {{ data|safe }};
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="some_unique_name(my_variable);">..</button>
```

and

(2)

```
<script>
    var foo = function () {
        some_unique_name({{ data|safe }});
    };
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="foo();">..</button>
```

Comment: I want to turn the JSON array to a javascript object that's why I'm using `JSON.parse`. I tried using backticks but it didn't work...

Comment: Didn't work isn't a problem description... The point I'm trying to make is that a json formatted string is a valid js expression, so you can insert it directly into the code, you don't need to parse it.

Comment: What I meant with didn't work is that the same problem I hav already described persists.
[this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) is what Django gives me after serializing the data to JSON. Any idea on how to use the serialized data without parsing them?

Comment: Yes, insert it into the code as per my answer. I've updated with the resulting code that you can check for yourself by using your browser's view-source function.

Comment: this is working in my HTML file when written like this:
`<script type=”text/javscript”>
var data = {{ data|safe}};
</script>`

When I try to do `var data = {{ data|safe }}; ` in my .js file I get this error:

`SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'`

Comment: Yes, of course. Why do you think you can use Django template language in a .js file that the browser loads completely outside Django?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how to pass data received from django template variables to a function defined in a .js file.

Comment: This seems to work. I moved my function to an onclick button `<button type="button" onclick="votingFunction({{ data|safe}})">Try it</button>`

but now I'm getting this error:


`SyntaxError: missing ] after element list note: [ opened at line 1, column 15`

Comment: Again, why do you think that should work. Look at the generated code using your browser's view-source function (seriously, do this! -- your shotgun w/o looking approach will only work by accident.. *sigh*). Hint: you've inserted code containing `"` into a string, causing it to be terminated right before `"model..`. (you can create `var foo = function () { votingFunction(...); };` and then use `onclick="foo()"`, but at some point you'll need to understand what you're doing (i.e. look at the view-source..)

Comment: I understand what's wrong but I'm not sure how to implement the code you provided. where am I supposed to put `{{data|safe}}`?

`var foo = function () { votingFunction(   What goes here??   );
here goes the rest of my code I guess
 };`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit tired. Didn't mean to be unfriendly. Answer updated.

Comment: Don't worry you didn't come out as unfriendly. I'm tired too. I've been working on this the whole day. Anyway I tried your first solution: `<script>
    var my_variable = {{ data|safe }};
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="some_unique_name(my_variable);">..</button>`

which gave me an error that I can't really replicate now for some reason... But the it clicked me and I changed the onclick parameter to use single quotes instead of double quotes and no it works great.

`<button type="button" onclick='votingFunction({{data|safe}})'>Try it</button>`